# Curl_cffi Timeout Problems

Tags: python, http, web-scraping, curl, python-asyncio

I'm running curl_cffi 0.5.7. I'm using AsyncSession with this code:

```
async def load_url(url: str, session: AsyncSession):
  try:
    ans = await session.get(url, proxies={proxieshere}, headers={headershere}, impersonate="chrome110", timeout=5)
    # ...
  except Exception as exc:
    print("Exception: {}".format(str(exc)))

async def setup():
    while 1:
        async with AsyncSession(max_clients=5) as session:
            tasks = []
            for url in urls:
                task = load_url(url=url, session=session)
                tasks.append(task)
            await gather(*tasks,return_exceptions=True)
```

It works as it should in the beginning, but after a while it starts slowing down, and timeouts begin becoming more frequent
Timeout Error:
`Failed to perform, ErrCode: 28, Reason: 'Operation timed out after 5005 milliseconds with 41047 bytes received'`.

Soon enough, these would cause the threads to hang. I fixed it by changing session.py from:

```
try:
    # curl.debug()
    await self.acurl.add_handle(curl)
    # print(curl.getinfo(CurlInfo.CAINFO))
    curl.clean_after_perform()
except CurlError as e:
    curl.reset()
    self.push_curl(curl)
    raise RequestsError(e)
rsp = self._parse_response(curl, req, buffer, header_buffer)
curl.reset()
self.push_curl(curl)
return rsp
```

to:

```
try:
    # curl.debug()
    await self.acurl.add_handle(curl)
    # print(curl.getinfo(CurlInfo.CAINFO))
except CurlError as e:
    raise RequestsError(e)
else:
    rsp = self._parse_response(curl, req, buffer, header_buffer)
    return rsp
finally:
    curl.reset()
    self.push_curl(curl)
```

It doesn't cause the threads to freeze anymore, but instead, once it starts slowing down after a while for no reason, only timeouts begin to happen for sometimes several minutes before it starts working as normal again, and then timeouts start to happen again. If I restart the program, it starts working again so there's no problem with my proxies.

Comment: any special reason for using CURL instead of  httpx ? 
At first glance your side of the code is correct, limiting the number of sessions - but if the Python wrapper over curl do a poor handling of its resources, the issues you are reporting might happen

Comment: @jsbueno I'm running curl_cffi instead of httpx since I need the fingerprints included in that package.

Comment: Have you tracked which URLs are slow? Is it possible that your scraping is being detected, and you're being throttled at the other end? Try your code against a webserver under your control, and see what happens.

Comment: @btilly The URLs are not slow. It happens no matter what URLs I choose. It's also not possible that I'm being detected and throttled since it works when I restart the script, and when I run it on a webserver that I'm running myself.

Comment: We have updated the code a lot since 0.5.7, could you please try to see if 0.5.10 works?